# How to remove duplicated rows in Postgres by two fields

Tags: postgresql

I need to remove only duplicated rows in a Postgres database, but I'm having some dificult to do this. I have some data rows that are duplicated and I need to remove them and keep only one by removing only the duplicated rows.

Example:

TableName="RegionCustomer"

```
Row - RegionId - CustomerId
 1  - REG1000  - CUS3000 
 2  - REG1000  - CUS4000
 3  - REG1000  - CUS3000
 4  - REG2000  - CUS3000
```

You can see in the row 1 and 3 that the values RegionId and CustomerId are duplicated, and I want to delete them. But i dont know how to do this :/

I have tried to group them by RegionId and CustomerId and this works, but don't know how to delete them.

[OriginalTable]

```
Row - RegionId - CustomerId
 1  - REG1000  - CUS3000 
 2  - REG1000  - CUS4000
 3  - REG1000  - CUS3000
 4  - REG2000  - CUS3000
```

[WhatINeed]

```
Row - RegionId - CustomerId
 1  - REG1000  - CUS3000 
 2  - REG1000  - CUS4000
 3  - REG2000  - CUS3000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete this way the duplicate rows by keeping single row of the **RegionId** and **CustomerId** combination,

**What it does:**

- Rank the rows based on RegionId, CustomerId group a.k.a the window
- Select only the id column of each window where the row_number is `>` 1
- Delete only those rows from the RegionCustomer table.

**QUERY:**

```
DELETE FROM RegionCustomer
WHERE id IN
    (
      SELECT id
      FROM 
        (
         SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY RegionId,
         CustomerId
         ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
         FROM RegionCustomer ) t
         WHERE t.row_num > 1 
    );
```

**Note:** Replace **id** with **Row** if that column name is **Row** instead of **id**,

Comment: OMG! Ty a lot man, this worked very well. Ty a lot, you saved my weekend. I will study more about postgres. A big hug from Brazil <3

Comment: @Drakron glad it helps. Hug from Bangladesh too :)